# restrict specific task when we run mlUndeploy in gradle

Tags: gradle, ml-gradle

How to restrict specific task to execute while running default task such as mlUndeploy or mlDeploy through gradle

I want to restrict below Task while running mlUn:

project.task("mlUndeployPrivileges", type: UndeployPrivilegesTask, group: securityGroup, description: "Undeploy (delete) each privilege in the configuration directory")

Comment: do you mean you want to skip execution of task `mlUndeployPrivileges` when you execute task `mlUndeploy ` (or `mlDeploy ` ) ?

Comment: @M.Ricciuti its **mlUndeploy**

Comment: you could disable task `mlUndeploy` dynamically depending on the tasks you execute:   `if (gradle.startParameter.taskNames.contains("mlUndeploy ")){
        tasks.findByName("mlUndeployPrivileges").enabled = false
    }`

Comment: Thank you @M.Ricciuti for help. I still see **mlUndeployPrivileges** is executed after adding the code snippet. I think _[task].enable = false_ will not application for task called by any gradle default task. when I run mlUndeploy the previleges are undeploy due to execution of mlUndeployPrivileges . Please assist

Comment: I could able to achieve the above by disabling dynamically through task command, something similar as suggested above  <br/> `if (gradle.startParameter.taskNames.contains("mlUndeploy")){            mlAppDeployer.getCommands().remove(mlAppDeployer.getCommand("DeployPrivilegesCommand"))
        }`